# How to compile avr c and c++ source code with make

Tags: makefile, avr, include-path

I was trying to compile some code written in c and c++ for an atmega32u4.
I wrote a makefile from information gathered from the internet, but it fails for some reason.
If I run the commands separately from the command line, they all work. However running the make command gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory
```

The contents of the main.cpp file are not really relevant, it's just a blink code.
The makefile looks like this:

```
all: init clean $(patsubst %.cpp, %.hex, $(wildcard *.cpp))
  avr-size -A $(BUILDPATH)/*.elf

%.c.o: %.c
  @mkdir -p $(BUILDPATH)
  avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -mmcu=$(CHIP) $^ -o $(BUILDPATH)/$@

%.cpp.o: %.cpp
  @mkdir -p $(BUILDPATH)
  avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -mmcu=$(CHIP) $^ -o $(BUILDPATH)/$@

%.elf: %.o
  avr-gcc -g -Os -w -mmcu=$(CHIP) $(BUILDPATH)/$^ -o $(BUILDPATH)/$@

%.hex: %.elf
  avr-objcopy -R .eeprom --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O ihex $(BUILDPATH)/$^ $(BUILDPATH)/$@
```

So what am I doing wrong? Do I have to set up some environment variables or is the structure of the makefile incorrect?

Comment: Are you sure `avr/io.h` exists? and if so, I do not see it in our include path.

Comment: Yes. I am sure, since the command executes successfully if I run it directly from the console.

Comment: Can you post how exactly you run it from the console? It may be beneficial.

Comment: Sure. Something like this: `avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -mmcu=atmega32u4 main.cpp -o target/main.o` than `avr-g++ -g -Os -w -mmcu=atmega32u4 target/main.o -o target/main.elf` and finally `avr-objcopy -R .eeprom --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O ihex main.elf main.hex`.